# Change of Variables - Find Integral Bounds

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume, jacobian

I am having trouble with determining the integral bounds in change of variable problems.

The problem:

Consider the transformation given by
$\space x = u - \sqrt{(\frac13)}\cdot v \space$ and $\space y = u + \sqrt{(\frac13)}\cdot v$ $- g(u,v) \space$ and $h(u,v)$ respectively

$R = {(x,y)\in R^2 : x^2 −xy+y^2 \le1}$  and
$S = {(u,v)∈ R^2 : (u - \sqrt{(\frac13)}\cdot v, u + \sqrt{(\frac13)\cdot v)} \in R}$

I understand that we take the integral of $f(g(u,v), h(u,v))\cdot\text{Jacobian} - \text{Jacobian}$ evaluates to $\frac{2}{\sqrt{(\frac13)}}$

This is where I get stuck. I know we can find the bounds for $x$ and $y$ from $x^2 −xy+y^2 \le1$ but I'm unsure how to convert that to $u,v$ variables.

In the problem I have to show this \begin{equation} \iint_Rx^2-xy+y^2\ dA=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}} \end{equation}

And also have to draw the transformation from $(x,y)$ to $(u,v)$

Comment: My question is what is your region R? What is your area bounded by?

Comment: The $x^2-xy+y^2$ is the multivariable function you are integrating.

Comment: Is the problem Type I or Type 2, is it $dydx$, or $dxdy$

Comment: To me at least your problem is missing the initial region, whether it's type 1 or type 2, the point of the transformation, your determinant on how you got your Jacobian, your partials. Things that would help solve the problem.

Comment: if $x=u-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}v$, and $y=u+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}v$, then you Jacobian is setup as follows. \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\delta x}{\delta u}&\frac{\delta x}{\delta y}\\ \frac{\delta y}{\delta u} & \frac{\delta y}{\delta v}\end{bmatrix}

Comment: which gives you the determinant of the following matrix $\mathbf{det}(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\ 1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \end{bmatrix})$? Which the Jacobian equals the following:$\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: I think this where you get confused because you are supposed to multiply your function with the Jacobian plugged in into the function. Because the whole integral does not evaluate to that value.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the assignment of the variables $u(x, y) = \dfrac{x + y} 2$ and $v(x, y) = \dfrac{\sqrt 3(y - x)} 2.$ We have that $$u^2 + v^2 = \frac{x^2 + 2xy + y^2} 4 + \frac{3(y^2 - 2xy + x^2)} 4 = x^2 - xy + y^2.$$ Consequently, we obtain a transformation $G(x, y) = (u(x, y), v(x, y))$ with Jacobian $$\operatorname{Jac}(G) = \det \begin{pmatrix} \frac 1 2 & -\frac{\sqrt 3} 2 \\ \frac 1 2 & \phantom -\frac{\sqrt 3} 2 \end{pmatrix} = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}.$$ Observe that the region in the $uv$-plane that is mapped onto by $G$ is given by $0 \leq u^2 + v^2 \leq 1,$ i.e., the disk of radius $1$ centered at the origin. Using polar coordinates, this region is $\{(r, \theta) \,|\, 0 \leq r \leq 1 \text{ and } 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi\}.$ By the Change of Variables Formula, therefore, we have that $$\iint_R (x^2 - xy + y^2) \, dA = \frac 2 {\sqrt 3} \iint_U (u^2 + v^2) \, dA = \frac 2 {\sqrt 3} \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 r^3 \, dr \, d \theta = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 3}.$$